# How did 'à savoir' semantically shift to mean 'c’est-à-dire'?

Tags: étymologie

Undeniably, "savoir" and "dire" are different concepts. Thus how do they appertain to each other? The same semantic shift also happened in English, from "that is to wit" to "that is to say".

> #### wit

> Both the noun *wit* [OE] and the verb [OE] go
> back ultimately to the Indo-European base
> **woid-, *weid-, *wid-*. This originally meant
> ‘see’, in which sense it has given English *visible*,
> *vision*, etc, but it developed metaphorically to
> ‘know’, and it is this sense that lies behind
> English *wit*. The noun to begin with denoted
> ‘mind, understanding, judgement, sense’ (a
> meaning preserved in expressions such as ‘keep
> one’s wits about one’ and ‘slow-witted’), and the
> modern sense ‘clever humorousness’ did not
> begin to emerge until the 16th century. The verb
> has now virtually died out, except in the
> expression *to wit*. *Witness* is etymologically the
> state of ‘knowing’. Other English words that
> come from the same Indo-European base or its
> Germanic descendant include *guide, history,
> idea, story*, and *twit*.

John Ayto, *Word Origins* (2005 2e), p 549 Left column. Below I quote Etymonline on the verb ["wit"](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=wit):

> "to know" (archaic), Old English *witan* (past tense wast, past participle witen) "to know, beware of or conscious of, understand, observe, ascertain, learn,"
> from Proto-Germanic **witanan* "to have seen," hence "to know" (source also of Old Saxon *witan*, Old Norse *vita*, Old Frisian *wita*, Middle Dutch, Dutch *weten*, Old High German *wizzan*, German *wissen*, Gothic *witan* "to know"), from PIE root [*weid-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*weid-) "to see."

> The phrase *to wit*, almost the only surviving use of the verb, is first recorded 1570s, from earlier *that is to wit* (mid-14c.), probably a loan-translation of Anglo-French *cestasavoir*, used to render Latin *videlicet* (see [viz.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/wit)).

Comment: "C'est à savoir" ne signifie pas "C'est à dire". C'est "A savoir" qui signifie "C'est à dire".

Answer (score 3):

I do not think one can dissect phrases and try to reconstruct the meaning of each word that builds them. Phrases should be considered as new entities altogether, and they often are since dictionaries often have distinct entries for them. So I do not agree in saying *savoir* and *dire* "appertain to each other" semantically.

*Savoir* has a lot of different meanings. In the phrase *[à savoir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_savoir)* the meaning implied is that of *connaitre*, but even then, as is often the case with phrases and, as stated in [*Le Robert*](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/savoir) the original meaning of the verb is weakened.

When I use ***à savoir*** I intend to explain something, to **make** something **known** to the person I am talking to.

In ***c'est-à-dire*** the meaning of *dire* is *expliquer*, as found in the [*Dictionnaire de Furetière*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50614b/f648.item)<sup>1</sup>. When I use *c'est à dire* I intend to give an explanation to the person I am talking to.

I would venture to say that *c'est-à-dire* could be seen from the angle of the one who is explaining, and *à savoir* from the angle of the one who is receiving the information.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> DIRE, signifie encore simplement, Expliquer. Cet endroit est obscur, mais l'Auteur veut *dire* que.</sup>